# juego estilo 3D con unity o con otra tecnología

Tags: unity3d

Me gustaría conocer cual es la mejor opción para un juego estilo 3D (Android) con unity o con otra tecnología.

No me importa si es de pago pero me gustaría ver otra opción para mas capacidad en el desarrollo

Comment: Gilberto, esta pregunta **se basa principalmente en opiniones** ya que cada uno puede decirte que "la mejor" es una u otra. Deberias  objetivizar la pregunta añadiendo unos requisitos que quieras que tu juego tenga para que se te diga qué teconologia recoge esos requisitos. O puedes hablarlo con la gente del [chat general](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol) donde las preguntas son totalmente coloquiales y puedes preguntar opiniones. Un saludo

Comment: Android es un sistema operativo. Unity 3D es un IDE. No tienen nada que ver uno con el otro, así que la pregunta no tiene sentido alguno.

Answer (score 1):

Basándome en la pregunta en si misma, entre Android (intuyo que te refieres a AndroidStudio o un IDE compatible con la programación en Android) y Unity3D, usaría Unity3D.

No es por vendertelo, pero en cuestión de potencia, Unity3D da la talla de sobras, además de poder exportar tus juegos para Android, PC y IOS.

La "pega" es que si el juego que quieres es principalmente para Android y estas acostumbrado al Java, he de decirte que Unity3D usa C#. No es que C# sea muy diferente de Java pero te aconsejo, si no has tocado nunca que le des un repaso al C#.

También he de añadir que con Unity3D es muy fácil crear un juego sin apenas tocar código salvo en cosas muy específicas.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Mmm gracias por tu comentario